# In Django 1.7, how can I have one of two model fields required?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a django based web app to index some online learning resources, such as MOOCS.  Some MOOCS are 'open' meaning they can be started at any time, at the learners own pace, while others have a defined start and end date.  It makes sense to me that if the course is open, start date should not be required, but if it is not open, I would like start date to be required.  Is there ant way to do this in my model.py, or should it be handled solely with form validation.  Thanks for the help.

Currently:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    url = models.URLField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date course starts', null=True, blank=True)
    open = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to know how to use form validation, so to answer your question:

What you are trying to do is best accomplished using form validation as you said. Now, if you want to do this on a **model level**, in a way that you would have integrity (not DB integrity, but logical integrity), you should override the model's `clean` method. You can do this via something along the lines of:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.open and not self.start_date:
        raise ValidationError('This course is not open, therefore you need a start date')
    return super(Post, self).clean()
```

Now, if you want an added layer of logical integrity by also forcing `clean()` to run when you `save()` a model instance via command line, you can call `self.clean()` in the `save()` model method as well (note that this will run `self.clean()` twice in non-command line instances). Here is an example of what the final code can look like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    url = models.URLField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date course starts', null=True, blank=True)
    open = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.open and not self.start_date:
            raise ValidationError('This course is not open, therefore you need a start date')
        return super(Post, self).clean()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```